# problem with gpio write

Tags: gpio

I have a strange problem - this sequence switches the a relay connected to pin 1 ( reliably )

```
gpio mode 1 in
gpio mode 1 out
```

this does nothing:

```
gpio mode 1 out
gpio write 1 0
gpio write 1 1
```

Comment: I would guess your relay is operated by sinking rather than sourcing current.  But since you did not supply any details that is only a guess.

Comment: it is a rather standard relay board of ebay like this: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51kFbMU+3gL.jpg
I think I just get the documentation of gpio wrong as the switching ( hardware ) seems to work

Comment: You should really edit your question to add the details of the relay module you actually have.  If someone has the same module they may be able to help.  Make sure the details are for your module, not just a similar looking module.

Comment: @joan no, sinking vs sourcing makes no difference to the stated problem.  Regardless of which it is doing, writing both values should accomplish a change of state, the only question is in which direction.  But that did not happen, so the problem is something else.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, that's probably wrong.  I've seen this before with some relay modules, they switch if you change the mode between input and output rather than on level change.  I don't remember the explanation.